# codeigniter disallowed key characters for one user only

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

There are many questions about codeigniter disallowed key characters but I could not find one similar to this.

I have an app where a method is working fine for all but one user. For one user they are receiving the codeigniter disallowed key characters error (and no further info as errors are off and I don't have access to the logs). All I know is that the URL of the error page ends in {uri}.

As I can't find a way to replicate this could it be a cookie issue? If so how would I go about tracking down the bug?

Let me know if you need code. I have assumed it would not be helpful if its working for most people

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Just let the user clear his/her browser cookies and temporary internet files.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a shot but would be nice to track down the issue